# fatal error LNK1103: debugging information corrupt; recompile module

Tags: visual-c++

I am using VS 2017 with version 15.3.0. I have a project with C++ source codes that can be built successfully in VS version 15.2 but failed in 15.3 with the following error:

> msxml2.lib(msxml2_i.obj) : fatal error LNK1103: debugging information corrupt; recompile module

Does anyone have suggestions about this?

Answer (score 1):

I have filed a bug report to Microsoft including a sample application which reproduces the bug:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/99785/mfcs140libstdafxobj-fatal-error-lnk1103-debugging.html

Hopefully this will be fixed in a subsequent 15.3.x update.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when my project use an external lib(CyAPI.lib).
I tried delete the Debug folder, and recompiled, but the problem still exist.

I resolved the problem by changed to CyAPI.lib to the newest version.